# SwiftUI - List - UIViewRepresantable won't be updated

Tags: swiftui

In my list, my UIViewRepresentable won't be updated if it is the only item in list. If I add e.g. a Text to it, it works. To see the effect, scroll down and up again.
What am i doing wrong?

Hers is my code:

```
struct Test : UIViewRepresentable {

    var text : String

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Test>) -> UILabel {
        UILabel()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Test>) {
        uiView.text = text
    }

    typealias UIViewType = UILabel
}

class Data : ObservableObject {

    @Published var names = UIFont.familyNames
}

struct ContentView : View {

    @EnvironmentObject var data : Data

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(data.names, id: \.self) { name in
                Test(text: name)
        //        Text(name)  // as soon as you comment this out, it works
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: I run a copy of your code and everything is working fine when UIViewRepresentable is only view in the List

Comment: did you scroll up and down?

Comment: Yes several times

Comment: Confirm issue. Tested on Version 11.2.1 (11B500).

Comment: my Version is Version 11.2.1 (11B500) too

Comment: my version is 11.0

Comment: Might be bug from the your version

Comment: Updated correctly if List is replaced with ScrollView/ForEach, so it seems List's issue.

Comment: Hi Asperi, thx for your quick and right answer...but...if i use scrollview and for each this is not usable for big lists, because it calls the "row" for the whole list, instead of List, which reuses rows.

Comment: Yes, it's not an answer or solution, but rather investigation results to narrow the problem area. And as it seems (observing view hierarchy) the problem is exactly in reused cells.

Comment: Tested on Xcode 11.3 beta (11C24b). Now it is updated, but... after update, although it is visible, it lost leading padding, so looks a bit ugly. I recommend to submit radar.

Comment: just testet 13.0 + 13.1 -> works 13.2 -> does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I know variant/workaround that works (tested on all available Xcode 11.x)

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List(data.names, id: \.self) { name in
            Test(text: name).id(name) //           << here !!
        }
    }
}
```

Note: it might be performance drop on very big lists, but in most usual cases it is not remarkable.

PS: By the way, about `class Data` - don't name your classes with same names as system one, there might be confuses and unexpectable issues.