# Problems with layout of some rows in SwiftUI list

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have tried to find a similar problem asked before, but failed.

I have a simple view with list. I am using a ForEach to show 10 iterations of the some list item to create a layout before I will add real data to this list. I have a problem with last 2 rows not rendering correctly. But sometimes it’s other row. I have tested on an iPhone too and sometimes it’s one row, sometimes another. The code for the view with list is this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LocksView: View {

    @State private var locksPaid = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                DateView()
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())

                Picker(selection: $locksPaid, label: Text("Picker")) {
                    Text("All").tag(0)
                    Text("Not paid (2)").tag(1)
                }
                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                .padding(10)

                ForEach(0 ..< 10) {item in
                    LocksItemView()
                }

            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Locks"))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        }
    }
}
```

The code for list items is this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LocksItemView: View {

    @State private var paid : Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack {

            Text("L15")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .frame(width: 80)

            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("nickname")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                Text("category")
                Text("4 000 THB")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
            }

            Spacer()

            Toggle(isOn: self.$paid) {
                Text("Paid")
            }
            .labelsHidden()
        }
    }
}
```

Why is toggle broken in some rows on my list? Why it moves to the left side?

[image]

Comment: It seems it's fixed in iOS 13.4 and Xcode 11.4 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code at simulators first and had same issue too. But then I remembered, that there are some problems with 13.2 iOS and tried to run it on my device (iPhone 7, iOS 13.1.1) and everything works fine! I think that is the problem in 13.2 iOS, not in the List. There is sample, how I changed code for demonstration that everything is ok:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct LocksView: View {
    
    @State private var locksPaid = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Picker(selection: $locksPaid, label: Text("Picker")) {
                    Text("All").tag(0)
                    Text("Not paid (2)").tag(1)
                }
                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                .padding(10)

                ForEach(0 ..< 200) {item in
                    LocksItemView(number: item)
                }

            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Locks"))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        }
    }
}

struct LocksItemView: View {

    @State private var paid : Bool = false
    var number: Int

    var body: some View {
        HStack {

            Text("L\(self.number)")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .frame(width: 80)

            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("nickname")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                Text("category")
                Text("4 000 THB")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
            }

            Spacer()

            Toggle(isOn: self.$paid) {
                Text("Paid")
            }
            .labelsHidden()
        }
    }
}
```

and on my phone the result is:

[image]

so there are bugs in 13.2 version and I hope Apple will fix them all

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for that observation. How can I file a bug with a SwiftUI? I will try to solve this problem for a while. Maybe adding ID for rows will help? Maybe now the rows are not treated 100% as separate rows? Just a guess. But your discovery shows that even with this exact code is working on previous iOS. Thanks!

Comment: @mallow, I think https://feedbackassistant.apple.com is right place to file this bug, maybe today later I'll do it too

Comment: Thanks! I will do it it. I have filed few bugs there about macOS or iOS but they were never fixed and very rarely my submissions were answered at all. So I was hoping there is some better way :)

Comment: @mallow, review sent to Apple, but I think it shouldn't disturb you to do the same =)

Comment: Александр Thank you very much for doing this. I have just submitted the bug by myself as well. I have also installed new Simulator in my Xcode with iOS 13.1 and the same as you told me - everything looks perfect on this. I hope Apple will fix the bug in the next iOS update.

Comment: This bug is still present in 13.3. :/

Answer (score 2):

It is not last items. If you set in your `ForEach` 20 instead of 10 and scroll up & down you'll see much more interesting issue.

I assume the reason, actually `List` bug, is the same as in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58930429/swiftui-list-uiviewrepresantable-wont-be-updated).

**Workaround** If it is not critical to you then use `ScrollView` instead of `List`, as tested there is no bug for it. Otherwise, file a Radar and wait for fix.

Comment: Thanks @Asperi. I am using List, because ScrollView was causing other problems. I think I will stick with the List for a while and try to solve this problem. If not so need to solve other problems with the ScrollView :)

Comment: BTW, thanks for that observation that it’s not always last 2 rows. I tested again on my phone at sometimes it’s one row sometimes another. I have updated my question

Comment: Asperi, your workaround works. Just tried. Thanks for this! But as I said I had some issues with ScrollView. And as @Александр found this is probably a bug and I hope it will be solved in next iOS update. If not, I will try to use your workaround and fix issues with scrollview.